# Trust computer from Apple Watch

Tags: mac, security, apple-watch, privacy

My Apple Watch asked me if I trust a Mac. I reluctantly clicked Yes. Now I wonder which Mac did I let it trust. How can I make sure that it is my Mac? Is there a list of trusted devices/computers on my Mac or on my Apple Watch?